# netsh port proxy doesn't always work for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, netsh

I have a Mac running Windows 10 21H1 in Parallels. On macOS I have SQL Server running in a Docker container, exposed on port 55556.
In Windows I'm trying to forward localhost,55555 to the SQL Server in Docker.
For this I tried `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=localhost listenport=55555 connectaddress=10.211.55.2 connectport=55556`, but this only works when connecting in DataGrip (in the Windows VM, using a JDBC driver); I can see all the databases, query them, etc.
SQL Management studio always gives the following error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 258)
```

Is there something about the driver that SQL Management studio uses that ignores this port forwarding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out: portproxy with listen address localhost doesn't work, but 127.0.0.1 does.